# javascript: dynamic textareas sends only last generated textarea value

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a Tinymce textarea which is dynamic. i.e more instance of the textarea can be cloned and also have TinyMce plug-in being attached for each.

The issue I'm having is that, if e.g more textareas were cloned and the user enters values into the diffetrent textareas and on submission of the form, only the last textarea value is posted (using PHP scripting).

So, it's apparent that the issue is from the javascript I'm using to generate the textareas cos I expect all the textareas to be binded to a name property like this

```
content[]
```

and then sent via $_POST as an array but it's sending just the last generated textarea value.

**Here is my js**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.relCopy = function (options) {
        var settings = jQuery.extend({
            excludeSelector: ".exclude",
            emptySelector: ".empty",
            copyClass: "copy",
            append: '',
            clearInputs: true,
            limit: 0 // 0 = unlimited
        }, options);

        settings.limit = parseInt(settings.limit);

        // loop each element
        this.each(function () {

            // set click action
            $(this).click(function () {                
                var $clone = $(template);

                $('form').find('.cloneEmp:last').after($clone);

                initTinyMCE(); // re-attach plug-in to include new DOM

                return false;
            }); // end click action

        }); //end each loop

        return this; // return to jQuery
    };

})(jQuery);
```

other js in the head tag

```
var template = '<div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp"><p><label><strong>Text Box</strong></label><textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea><div class="clear"></div></p></div>';

function initTinyMCE() {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "simple"
    });
}

$(function () {
    var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" style="float:right; margin-top:-20px; margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">remove</a>';
    $('a.add').relCopy({
        append: removeLink
    });
});

initTinyMCE();
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="add_res_form">
        <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
            <div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp">
                <p>
                    <label><strong>Text Box</strong>

                    </label>
                    <textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p><a href="#" class="add add_res_submit" rel=".cloneEmp">Add More Text</a>

            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

demo in jsFiddle showing the textarea being cloned

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sammie85/tPbdh/3/)

Would be pleased to getting help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "var template" in the head with this:-

```
var template = '<div class="clone_box_holder cloneEmp"><p><label><strong>Text Box</strong></label><textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea><div class="clear"></div></p><p><label><strong>Another Text Box</strong></label><textarea class="mceSimple" name="content[]"></textarea><div class="clear"></div></p></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the question by removing the other textarea, thereby making it just one textarea in the html form. And to your suggestion, I have tried that initially but still did not work.